# How to render components using function in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi i'm new to React native and trying render components by calling a function inside render but it doesn't seem to work.

my function:

```
renderData = () => {
    this.state.data.map(x => {
      return (
         <View>
           <Text> {x.data.title} </Text>
         </View>
       )
    });
  };
```

Works if i do this:

```
  render() {

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Enter Username</Text>
        {this.state.data.map(x => {
          return <Text style={styles.bodyText}> {x.data.title} </Text>;
        })}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

But not this:

```
  render() {

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Enter Username</Text>
        {this.renderData()}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
   }
  }
```

I'm lost as to why it doesn't work with the second code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you aren't returning anything from `renderData` to actually render. Add a return statement:

```
return this.state.data.map(x => {
  return (
     <View>
       <Text> {x.data.title} </Text>
     </View>
   )
});
```

You actually have to return the new mapped elements so that when you call it in `{this.renderData()}` you get the new elements. Or else you're doing `{undefined}` since you currently have no return value.